# My Wait() method works in 'Chrome' & 'Firefox' but not in 'IE'?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My Wait() method works in 'Chrome' & 'Firefox' but not in 'IE', any ideas?

I have tried using IEDriverServer.exe both the 32bit and the 64bit(Send keys acts slow), but the following method still dosnt click on the intended target.

Please note: I know the locators are fine as listed above works in both Chrome and firefox.

```
public void waitAndClickFirstDrivingExperiencesOption(WebElement element) throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Base_Page basePage = new Base_Page(driver);
    try {
        System.out.println(basePage.browser_type);
        Boolean elementPresent = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).isEnabled();
        if (elementPresent == true) {
            if (!this.browser_type.equals("firefox")) {
                // Provide a slight timeout before clicking on the element
                basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                basePage.actionMoveAndClick(element);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                element.click();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Clicked on the first supercars link, using locator: " + element.toString());
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException elementUpdated) {
        element = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='prd_listing']/div/li[1]/a"));
        Boolean elementPresent = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).isEnabled();
        if (elementPresent == true) {
            if (!this.browser_type.equals("firefox")) {
                basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                basePage.actionMoveAndClick(element);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                element.click();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(
                "Clicked on the first supercars link (Stale Exception), using locator: " + element.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception! - could not click on the first supercars link, Exception: " + e.toString());
        throw (e);
    } finally {
    }
```

Comment: Add the code for `actionMoveAndClick` too because that one is executed for non-Firefox browsers.

Comment: In rare cases, I've heard xpaths aren't the same in IE which might be causing your issue. Which line is failing, and what is the locator for the element that isn't working?